# re render click event for added element backbone

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, backbone.js

I'm currently new in backbone.js. I use CodeIgniter as my PHP Framework.

I'm developing an existing system which uses a backbone.js library. My problem is easy if i will do it in jquery but since this uses a backbone.js, I should do it the same way. This what happens.

Once the page is loaded, i will populate the users inside a select box. then with a button 'ADD'. I will populate also the uses already added inside the `ul` element to list all the users with an `x` anchor if you want to delete the user.

I append the user in the list after success ajax in create warehouse user. I use jquery to append. Now the click event to delete is not working because backbone already done rendering the views. How to re render backbone click event for newly added element?

[image]

Below is my sample code

HTML CODE

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-list"></i> User Access
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>warehouse/user" id="add-warehouse-user-form">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="users">Available Users </label>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="wh_id" id="wh_id" value="<?php echo $warehouse->wh_id; ?>" />
                                    <select class="form-control" name="users" id="users">
                                        <?php if(!empty($users)){
                                            foreach($users as $row){
                                                //if(in_array('Head',$row->user_access) AND $row->status == 'ACTIVE'){
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$row->user_id.'">'.$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name.'</option>';
                                                //}
                                            }
                                        }?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="users">&nbsp; </label>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" value="Add" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <ul class="list-group" id="list_user">
                                <?php if(!empty($userlist)){
                                    foreach ($userlist as $ul) {
                                        echo '<li class="list-group-item">'.$ul['name'].' <span class="badge badge-delete"><a class="deleteUser" href="#" data-id="'.$ul['module_id'].'" data-uid="'.$ul['id'].'" data-name="'.$ul['name'].'">x</a></span></li>';
                                    }
                                } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Warehouse model

```
var WarehouseUserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: Config.apiBaseUrl + "/warehouse/user",
  defaults: {
    wh_id: "",
    users: ""
  }  
});
var WarehouseUserDelModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: Config.apiBaseUrl + "/warehouse/user"
});
```

Warehouse View

```
var WarehouseView = Backbone.View.extend();
//-------------- add user to warehouse --------------//
var WarehouseUserAddNewView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#add-warehouse-user-form",
  loaderEl: "#form-loader",  
  events:{
    "submit": "createWarehouseUser"
  },

  createWarehouseUser: function (e) {
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = Util.getFormData($(self.el));

    var warehouseUser = new WarehouseUserModel(formData);

    //disable form
    $(self.el).find(" :input").prop("disabled", true);
    //show loader
    $(self.loaderEl).removeClass("hidden");

    warehouseUser.save({}, {
      success: function (model, res, options) {
        if (res.status == "error") {

          Util.formError(res.data);
          var errorTemplate = _.template($("#toast-error-template").html());
          toastr.error(errorTemplate({errors: res.data}));

          //re-enable form
          $(self.el).find(" :input").prop("disabled", "");
          //hide loader
          $(self.loaderEl).addClass("hidden");          

        } else {
          //location.href = res.data.redirectUrl;
          /** append user to list and remove from select box **/
          $('#list_user').append('<li class="list-group-item">'+$("#users option[value='"+$("#users").val()+"']").text()+' <span class="badge badge-delete"><a class="deleteUser" href="#" data-id="'+res.data.id+'" data-uid="'+$("#users").val()+'" data-name="'+$("#users option[value='"+$("#users").val()+"']").text()+'">x</a></span></li>');
          $("#users option[value='"+$("#users").val()+"']").remove();
          //re-enable form
          $(self.el).find(" :input").prop("disabled", "");
          //hide loader
          $(self.loaderEl).addClass("hidden");
        }
      }
    });
  },
  initialize: function () {},
});
//-------------- remove user from warehouse --------------//
var WarehouseUserDeleteView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: ".deleteUser",
  events:{
    "click": "deleteWarehouseUser"
  },

  deleteWarehouseUser: function (e) {
    elem = $(e.currentTarget)[0];
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    var warehouseUser = new WarehouseUserDelModel({'id':$(elem).data('id')});
    warehouseUser.destroy({
      success: function (model, res, options) {
        console.log(model);
        console.log(res);
        console.log(options);
        if (res.status == "error") {

          Util.formError(res.data);
          var errorTemplate = _.template($("#toast-error-template").html());
          toastr.error(errorTemplate({errors: res.data}));
        } else {
          /** append user to select box and remove from lists **/
          $("#users").append("<option value='"+$(elem).data('uid')+"'>"+$(elem).data('name')+" </option>");
          $(elem).parents('li.list-group-item').remove();
        }
      }
    });
  },
  initialize: function () {},
});

new WarehouseUserAddNewView();
new WarehouseUserDeleteView();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LinusJuhlin How to re render backbone for click event for newly added element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual code that renders your list of users will probably always be jquery - backbone does not come with default `render` functionality. However, it is common practice to put code that will render the entire contents of the `el` in a `render` method of the view. That way it can be called initially, and then called again whenever conditions have changed.

It looks like your general approach is to use each view a bit like an event handler. Each has a single event attached, with one sizeable method to do some work. That's fine as long as it's working for you, but you can also have a more complicated view than handles multiple functions. I might recommend you use your `WarehouseView` to keep a list of users, and handles both a reusable render, and the delete method you have already written:

```
var WarehouseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#list_user',
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.users = (options && options.users) || [];
        // render once on intialize
        this.render();
    },
    events: {
        // listen for delete clicks on contained elements
        'click .deleteUser': 'deleteWarehouseUser',
    },
    deleteWarehouseUser: function(ev) {
        // your same method code should work here
    },
    render: function() {
        // render the list of users you have
        this.$el.html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
            // use jquery to add the user to your list as a <li>
        }
    }
});

var warehouseView = new WarehouseView();
```

If you use this approach, then inside your add new user method you can do things like:

```
// ... create your user variable
warehouseView.users.push(user);
warehouseView.render();
```

The delete (client-side) can also consist of removing a particular user from your view's list, and then rerendering.

You can arrange backbone objects pretty much any way you like, but I hope this recommendation helps. Also note that once you feel more comfortable, creating a Backbone `Collection` for your users is the more "backbone-y" way to do things rather than a plain array.

Comment: Thank you for this one. I am really new in backbone js and i tried doing some tutorials. It makes my brain pump. If you can show me the example of collection on how to do this much better!.. Don't worry i understand your explanation very well and i'm now learning this render thing in view.

Comment: Hi, glad it helped. Compared to the other things you are learning, using a Backbone Collection instead of an array would be fairly easy. You define a collection similar to the Models and Views, and once it's created, it sort of acts like an array, but with lots of extra functionality. I wouldn't convert to this unless it's for a reason, like you want to encapsulate certain methods, or attach event handlers when your collection changes, etc. Documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection

Comment: i got a problem warehouse.js?ts=15982f98973e0c:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
    at child.initialize (warehouse.js?ts=15982f98973e0c:4)

Comment: If it's where you define the `this.users` property of your view, it can be fixed using: `this.users = (options && options.users) || [];`.  I updated the answer with this.

Comment: Thank you!! i made it working!!! i mean WE MADE IT!.. btw. can i add the `Add User` function to View also? because the delete function is already there.

Comment: The great thing about Backbone is there are lots of different ways it can work, so you can sort of do whatever you want! My instinct would be to leave the View that handles `Add User` separate, because the DOM elements it uses (the add button) are not handled by the View I gave above. In my mind, the View I gave is in charge of the list and delete buttons, because it draws the html for those. Of course, there are ways to make your views communicate and share the work to add a user as well, but that might not fit in a comment...

Comment: I get it now. My add user elements are not in the scope of `#list_user` elements. am i right?

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez right. Although, that is just how I would do things (have a view handle what is within it's DOM scope). Others might do things differently.